# Cuda Thrust min_element crashes

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have the following code snippet

```
uint64_t myvec[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

int main(void)
{   
  uint64_t* dev;    
  cudaMalloc(&dev, 5*sizeof(uint64_t));
  cudaMemcpy(dev,myvec,sizeof(uint64_t)*5,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);  
  uint64_t* min_iter = thrust::min_element(thrust::device, dev, dev+5);

  return 0;
}
```

This code crashes with a segfault because of min_element on device.

But this code seems to be working if i perform it on host

```
uint64_t* min_iter = thrust::min_element(thrust::host, myvec, myvec+5);
```

I don't know what's wrong. I am using cuda 7.5. Is this a bug?

Comment: This seems to be a bug: https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/776. You can work around it with this: `uint64_t* min_iter = thrust::min_element(thrust::device, thrust::device_pointer_cast(dev), thrust::device_pointer_cast(dev+5)).get();`

Answer (score 2):

This has been confirmed as a [bug](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/776) in Thrust. In comments, it was suggested that this:

```
uint64_t* min_iter = thrust::min_element(thrust::device,   
                         thrust::device_pointer_cast(dev), 
                         thrust::device_pointer_cast(dev+5)).get();
```

would work around the problem.

There now appears to be a [patch](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/pull/777) which has been added to the current Thrust development branch to address this problem.

[This answer has been mostly assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered question list for the CUDA tag].